# Can't install module 'conda_package_handling' on Windows 10

Tags: conda

I have just installed conda on Windows 10 but when I run commands like 'conda info', I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1043, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_update.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .install import install
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda_package_handling'
```

I have tried installing 'conda_package_handling' as instructed at https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda-package-handling and https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8607, but it won't let me install it - I get the same error message. I'd appreciate any leads on this!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error in ubuntu 16, and I solved this question as follows:
1. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/conda-package-handling/files, download the proper version based on your system. I downloaded conda-package-handling-1.3.11-py36_0.tar.bz2.
2. extract this file, then copy 'conda-package-handling-1.3.11-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_package_handling' to '/home/emg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages'
3. maybe this error can be fixed, but when i run 'conda info ', i met a new error, which was " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libarchive'"
4. https://pypi.org/project/libarchive/, run 'sudo apt-get install libarchive-dev'
5. finally, it was solved